# Why do we need to return in this recursive function

Tags: c, recursion

i'm trying to learn recursion, so i decide to implement some algorithms that used recursion like binary search but i have some problems to understand why we need return on some cases like this one:

```
int binarysearch(int *arr, int x, int left, int right){
    if(right <= left){
        return -1;
    }
    int mid = (left + right) / 2;
    if(arr[mid] == x){
        return mid;
    }
    if(x < arr[mid])
        return binarysearch(arr, x, left, mid - 1);
    else 
        return binarysearch(arr, x, mid + 1, right);
}
```

like we have no value that we need to return the only value we need are in the arguments, but when i remove the return statement i got some undefined behaviors.can someone explain to me why i got that undefined when i remove the return statement.

edit:

- this return statement: `return binarysearch(arr, x, left, mid - 1);`
- and this: `return binarysearch(arr, x, mid + 1, right);`

Comment: You refer to "the return statement", but there are 4 return statements.

Comment: The function returns the position in the array where it found the value

Comment: @PaulHankin i edit the question check it please

Comment: If you define a function to return some data type you have to use a `return` statement with a suitable value in every branch that ends the execution of the function. Otherwise you get undefined behavior.

Comment: @Bodo but in the return that i specify what value are returned ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it more clear, don't add questions in comments. Your function returns `-1`, `mid`  or the return value of a recursive call in `return binarysearch(...)`

Comment: @redeyes the value returned in those cases is the function result of calling the recursion with the altered arguments. Note how they're different than those on entry.

Comment: Aside: The function should have `if (right < left)`, not `if (right <= left)`. As written, the function searches the interval from `left` to `right` inclusive. (We can tell it is inclusive because once `mid` has been excluded, either `mid - 1` or `mid + 1` is used as an endpoint. An exclusive interval convention would use `mid`.)

Answer (score 2):

It is because the return value has to be propagated through the return value of every called function up into the original caller.

I will anotate every call by `[i]` just to distinguish different calls to the same function.

Lets say you have array `{ 1, 2 }`, and you call
`printf("%d", binarysearch[1](array, 2, 0, 1));`

Then

- `mid = 0` (because of rounding down when dividing two integers)
- `2 < arr[0] ~ 2 < 1 = 0` (`0` means `false` in C)

And therefore `binarysearch[2](array, 2, 1, 1);` is called inside `binarysearch[1]`. In this new function the `mid = 1` and `arr[1] == 2`, so the function `binarysearch[2]` returns `1`.

But `binarysearch[2]` was called inside `binarysearch[1]` so the value `1` is now inside `binarysearch[1]` and in order to get the value to the `printf`, we have to return it again.

If you delete the return (which I am surprised that the compiler even allows you to do), then the value returned from `binarysearch[2]` is discarded and `binarysearch[1]` ends without returning the value to the `printf`, but `printf` is expecting the value to be there, so it just takes whatever is in memory at that point and that results in undefined behavior.

I hope it is somewhat understandable.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that why we need to return the statements which are already present in the function.

So firstly the concept of recursion is function calling itself continuously.

Next the concept of binary search is to find an element in a list by dividing it into two.

It finds out the middle and compares it with the search element and if it is greater then the search value it carries out the search in the same way in the other part of the search.

The return statements you have mentioned are to call the functions again to repeat the function of search. i.e, to carry out the search in either first part of the list or second.

It does this function repeatedly until the element to be searched is found.

In simple words, the return statement takes back the control back to the start of the function. You can't have neglected the return because the function is declared as int and it has to have a return statement

Comment: what if we call the function without the return statement, is going to execute the function again or what ? <-- at this point i'm confused

Comment: The point of calling the function from return statement is that we have to return a value since the datatype of the function is int if you don't want to call it in the return statement then as per the previous example you can store the function call in a variable and return it. But you can't skip the return statement for functions of any datatype other than void